# Flash Player Issues

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium

Flash videos don't work online (namely YouTube, et al). I had tried reinstalling the flash player add-on and doing a system update but no improvement.

The problem started just after installing Ubuntu 12.04 i386. My browser is Mozilla Firefox, but the same issue exists in Chromium.

Comment: What do you mean by "Don't work"?  Does the page show the 'missing add-on' dialog or do the videos show up and not start playing.  Please be more specific with the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue on a at least 3 different computers. Here's what fixed it for me every time. Copy and paste these three commands into the terminal:

```
wget "http://ubuntuone.com/0maDagKUuWihfc8A2ktnlp" -O ~/flashplugin.tar.gz
tar xvzf flashplugin.tar.gz
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
```

What this does is install an older version of Adobe Flash. If this solves it, also type in these commands:

```
echo 'flashplugin-installer hold' | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Now type this in the terminal:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -i flash
```

And the correct result should be:

```
flashplugin-installer hold
```

This makes sure the computer doesn't update to a newer version of Adobe Flash that may not work. Hope this helps.